# Need Only Differing column values from two DataTables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, datatable, ado.net

I have two `DataTables` in which I need only differing column values in a final `DataTable` as shown below

**DataTable(DT1)**

```
ID  Name    Salary
1   ABC     2000
2   XYZ     4000
3   Suresh  6000
```

**DataTable(DT2)**

```
ID  Name    Salary
1   ABC     3000
2   XYZ     5000
3   Suresh  6000
```

**DataTable(DT3)**

```
ID  Salary(DT1) Salary(DT2)
1   2000             3000
2   4000             5000
```

How can I accomplish this using linq queries on Datatables or by any other way? I tried looping and comparing each column values both datatables, but I'm not getting how to store in final DataTables.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to join the tables (assuming the ID's have a PK/FK relationship), Then compare the values and place them in a new table.

```
    var unMatchedRows = from DataRow dt1Row in dt1.Rows
                        join DataRow dt2Row in dt2.Rows
                        on dt1Row["id"] equals dt2Row["id"]
                        where Convert.ToDoubl(dt1Row["salary"]) != Convert.ToDouble(dt2Row["salary"])
                        select new { dt1Row, dt2Row };
```

This gives us a collection of DataRow objects joined on the ID where the salary's are different.  Now we just need to populate a new DataTable with the rows.

```
    foreach (var m in unMatchedrows)
    {
        dt3.ImportRow(m);
    }
```

It is worth noting that DT3 will need to have the same schema as the other two tables. And this will only place the unmatched rows in the new table.  There are several ways to do this and I am not in front of an IDE right now to test it out, but this should get you going.  Hope this helps!